# Is it possible to make sure three of my docker instances run on different EC2 of ECS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, apache-kafka, amazon-ecs

For example, I need to deploy three docker instances to my ECS, which has three EC2. Is it possible to deploy these three docker instances to different EC2 machines?

I'm thinking deploy a kafka cluster, broker1, broker2, broker3 and zookeeper1, zookeeper2, zookeeper3 to three EC2 respectively.

Comment: yes it is possible you need orchestrations. such as Kubernetes or Docker swarm

Comment: There's a section in the ECS documentation on [Amazon ECS task placement](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-placement.html).  You can set it to _prefer_ different instances, but not to force it.  You could also install this software on dedicated instances and have your cluster connect to it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `BrokerService`, `ZooKeeperService` then the tasks will be balanced across availability zones by the [spread](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-placement-strategies.html) placement strategy already so this should occur, but it is true that if their wasn't sufficient capacity you might not get the ideal placement.

**Fargate Compute**

There are a couple of ways to force. The easiest I can think of is if `Fargate` was an option. This will ensure the highest level of high availability, but then you are forced to use Fargate, instead of `ec2`, which might breach your requirements, as you may for example need block storage which you don't get from Fargate. It could cost or save you money depending on if it would save you needing to deploy new ec2 instances, but you may have reserved instances which you want to use so it depends.

**Service Per AZ**
Otherwise you could create a service for each AZ. Each service will have a  `PlacementConstraints` using the [Cluster query language](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/cluster-query-language.html) to define which zone it should reside in:

```
"PlacementConstraints": [{
          "Type": "memberOf",
          "Expression": "attribute:ecs.availability-zone != us-east-1a"
        }
```

You would use `us-east-1{a-c}` for each service.

Creating different clusters having different instances in each AZ would also achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Look into [daemon services](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs_services.html).
ECS offers 2 service types - replica and daemon.

- Replica spreads tasks across availability zones and will place multiple tasks (Docker containers) on the same EC2 host to balance according to the placement strategy.
- Daemon places one task per service per EC2 container host to fulfill your expectation.

PS: Daemon services don't work with Fargate. Doesn't look like you are using Fargate anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [distinctInstance placement constraint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-placement-constraints.html) to place a service's replica tasks on different instances.